# Reading a NetSuite Item Fulfillment's shipcarrier field using suitescript 2.x

Tags: netsuite, suitescript2.0

I have a script which loads an item fulfillment record and from there I am trying to read the "shipcarrier" field.   This is a field that is shown on the IF page and if I put the &xml=t in the browser URL I can also see the value (such as Fed Ex or whatever).    The issue is, I am struggling with how to get that with the script I am writing.   I have noticed it does not appear to be in the schema browser but given that the UI shows it (and the help text shows 'shipcarrier'.  I would think there is some kind of way to read it even if it is not as simple as using getText() on the fulfillment record.      I have also seen some mention on other posts about it being set but again I don't seem to be able to read it and also .getFields() does not give it back either.

Comment: Do you need this to be available on the client or the server side? How do you need to get it exactly? Or what are you doing currently to try and get that field value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get that value using the search module and the lookupfields method.

```js
var fieldLookUp = search.lookupFields({
    type: search.Type.ITEM_FULFILLMENT,
    id: param_itemful_id,
    columns: ['shipcarrier']
});
```